# How could I catch an error when v-bind is given a wrong Font Awesome icon?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I allow users on my website to create links and append Font Awesome icons to it. They have the freedom to pick from any free icon and as such have to write something like 'fab fa-instagram'.

Since they have this freedom, if there's any typos or they input something that doesn't exist, this error is thrown.

[image: vue error]

This is how the code is like:

`<font-awesome-icon class="h-10 w-10 mr-auto" :icon="link.link_icon" @error="setBlank" />`

Is there a way I could catch the :icon error and swap the wrong icon with a string or something like that?

I tried @error but it apparently only works for :src in images.

Comment: is `font-awesome-icon` a component from you? Or a library Component?

Comment: If icon is wrong then issue is in your data not in Vue directive. You can verify the icon link in the link object you are binding.

Comment: @Mirko t. It's the Fort Awesome package.

Comment: @Rohìt Jíndal Yes, I know it's with the data. I'm trying to find a way to catch this error and replace it with a default icon like 'fa-question' since users have the freedom to type in any string. I want them able to pick out of 16k icons.

Comment: I have searched for a great documentation of the component, but sadly there isn't.
I guess what you can do is to check if icon exists through a method and pass the icon to your template only on existance. I haven't found an API to check if an Icon exists, maybe you need to search for it a bit, otherwise you probably will need a list that validatates for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the [component itself](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/blob/3.x/src/components/FontAwesomeIcon.js) does not emit an error event when an icon can't be found. <strike>I'd suggest to create an issue in the repository for that</strike> see [this issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/issues/385).

That means that you are only down to checking the DOM, e.g. the child elements of the component and see if they exist or not to determine whether the icon has been resolved correctly or not.
This can be done by using a `ref` on the icon component and check the children through the native DOM API.